# Python unexpected non-zero returncode when checking alias command set in .bashrc file

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, alias

I want to call an alias command set in a *.bashrc* file from python. However, the returncode of `source ~/.bashrc; command -v command` is for some reason 1 instead of 0 which is the case if the same command is executed directly in the shell. It should be noted that with a default command like `echo` instead of the alias command, python correclty returns 0 as the returncode.

To demonstrate the issue, I created a minimal example, where I use a regular shell script *define_alias.sh* instead of the *.bashrc* file:

**test_bash_command.py:**

```
import os
import subprocess

path_home = os.path.expanduser('~')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'source %s/define_alias.sh; command -v testcommand' % path_home], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

proc_stdout, proc_stderr = proc.communicate()
proc_returncode = proc.returncode

print("Returncode: %s" % proc_returncode)
print("Stdout: %s" % proc_stdout)
print("Stderr: %s" % proc_stderr)
```

**define_alias.sh:**

```
# .bashrc
# imagine this is a .bashrc file

echo "I'm in the shell script"
alias testcommand='echo THIS IS A TEST'
```

**Output:**

```
wssadmin /global/wss/fs01/fk_bpr/waif_v8
$ python test_bash_command.py
Returncode: 1
Stdout: b"I'm in the shell script\n"
Stderr: b''

wssadmin /global/wss/fs01/fk_bpr/waif_v8
$ env -i bash --norc --noprofile
bash-4.4$ bash -c "source /home/wssadmin/define_alias.sh; command -v testcommand; echo $?"
I'm in the shell script
0
bash-4.4$ source /home/wssadmin/define_alias.sh; command -v testcommand; echo $?
I'm in the shell script
alias testcommand='echo THIS IS A TEST'
0
bash-4.4$ exit
exit

wssadmin /global/wss/fs01/fk_bpr/waif_v8
$ source /home/wssadmin/define_alias.sh; command -v testcommand; echo $?
I'm in the shell script
alias testcommand='echo THIS IS A TEST'
0
```

**Question: Why is the returncode given to python not 0 like in the bash case? How can I get a returncode of 0 for the given command and additionally retrieve the stdout and stderr of the `command -v testcommand` (instead of only having that of the `echo` command)?**

The `source` command itself is executed, which can be seen in the printed `stdout` variable. Please do note that I would not like to change the `/bin/bash -c` nor the `shell=False` parameter in `subprocess.Popen` as otherwise I would get issues with other commands called in other python scripts by a `run_bash_cmd` function wrapped around the `subprocess.Popen`.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Aliases are disabled altogether by default in noninteractive shells. You can run `shopt -s expand_aliases` to turn them on. `command -v` is right to say (via its exit status) that there doesn't exist any valid instance of a command when the only defined version is an alias and alias expansion is turned off.

Comment: Also, think about testing the contents of `[[ ${BASH_ALIASES[testcommand]} ]]` if you want to know if something is _specifically_ an alias, as opposed to whether it's defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `shopt -s expand_aliases` to enable alias support, which is turned off by default in noninteractive shells. (Historically, aliases were part of the optional interactive extensions in the User Portability Utilities annex to the POSIX sh standard; it's only as of the Issue 7 revision to the POSIX standard that they're part of the proper base featureset).

```
>>> subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', 'alias foo=true;'
...                 'command -v foo']).returncode
1
>>> subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', 'alias foo=true;'
...                 'shopt -s expand_aliases; command -v foo']).returncode
alias foo='true'
0
```

If you want to actually *run* that alias, however, it needs to be defined (and alias expansion needs to be enabled) before parse time. To make simple statements be parsed individually, make sure they aren't part of a group or other compound statement, and separate them with newlines rather than `;`s or `&`s.

```
>>> subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', '\n'.join(['alias foo=true', 'foo'])],
...                env=(os.environ | {'BASHOPTS': 'expand_aliases'}))
CompletedProcess(args=['bash', '-c', 'alias foo=true\nfoo'], returncode=0)
```

Comment: You're a godsend. I would not have guessed this by myself. And here's your question-answered-checkmark :)

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, if you didn't already have aliases defined you were trying to use, I would suggest using functions instead -- a function is an actual first-class citizen with its own stack frame, argument list, local variables, &c; unlike aliases, they can be exported to subprocesses through the environment, they work in shells compiled with interactive extensions completely disabled, and they're much less likely to result in disapproving stares from old-timers. :P

Comment: The `testcommand` is recognized by `command -v`, but after sourcing the bashrc, I can nevertheless not run that alias command (simply by entering `testcommand`), even with the `shopt -s` flag. The `subprocess` call would be like `subprocess.Popen(/bin/bash -c source /home/wssadmin/.bashrc; shopt -s expand_aliases; testcommand, ...)`. Is there another flag that needs to be set?

Comment: Concretely, the stderr returned to python says `/bin/bash: testcommand: command not found`.

Comment: I read that aliases are not available on the same line that they are defined in. Is there a way to get around this (given that I cannot use two subprocess calls)?

Comment: You can pass a literal newline instead of `;` within the argument that follows `-c`, for one.

Comment: Another approach would be to turn on expand_aliases via the environment rather than in code run after the shell is finished initializing.

Comment: @bproxauf, does the answer you get need to work for code running as root, or is code that takes advantage of features that the shell turns off when running under uid 0 acceptable?

Comment: @bproxauf, ...updated accordingly, demonstrating both use of literal newlines and use of the BASHOPTS environment variable. Note that BASHOPTS may not work (version-dependent) when running as root -- newer versions of bash try to minimize attack surface when running as uid 0, and part of that is paying attention to fewer environment variables.